# jqGrid disable single selection

Tags: php, jqgrid

I'm using PHP with jqGrid to show the data.

I need to disable the selection function. Just show data.

Do anybody know how can I do that?

I only see examples of multiselection rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was referring to disable single selection the answer is this in the constructor of the grid:

```
beforeSelectRow : function (){
    return false;
}
```

So that prevent the selection happend.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused.

Are you referring to single/multiselecting rows grid option "multiselect:"?

If so:

1. find and remove the "multiselect:true" option from the grid definition.
   or
2. find and change the "multiselect" value from "true" to "false".

Comment: I was referring to disable single selection the answer is this in the constructor of the grid:
beforeSelectRow : function (){ //Avoids the selection
      return false;
}
But thanks anyway!